# Is it possible to connect foreground and background objects?

Tags: microsoft-visio

### Some context:

Let's say we have two pages:

1. "`bg_page`", which was created as "Background".
2. "`page_with_bg`", which was created as "Foreground",
   and uses "`bg_page`" as a background.

While editing "`page_with_bg`", I sometimes want to connect/resize/move shapes,
that come from "`bg_page`".

(My usecase for background functionality is to draw "AS-IS" and "TO-BE" pictures,
where most of the components on the screen stay unchanged.)

### Questions:

a. Is it possible to change "`bg_page`" objects,
while working inside "`page_with_bg`" **?** (without opening "`bg_page`")

b. Is it possible to connect "`page_with_bg`" objects, to objects from "`bg_page`"?

c. If it is not possible, are there any alternatives for similar usecases that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. No, only the current active page can be modified.

b. By "connect" I assume you mean with a Visio connector, in which case no. Connectors can only work between shapes on the same page.

c. There is a way to do this, but it involves creating and modifying shape formulae within the shapesheet editor. The exact details will depend upon what you want to do. It is difficult. First of all look at the shapesheet editor, how it works, how to reference other shapes, then look at how to reference other pages.